# SecureStore is skipped while I am accessing the login function and returns function error

Tags: react-native, expo

When I call loginUser function it suppose so access the SecureStore function but instead it is returning the from axios.post method.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

```
import { SecureStore } from 'expo';

export function loginUser(email, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.post(SIGNIN_URL, { email, password }).then((response) => {
      var { user_id, token } = response.data;
      Expo.SecureStore.setItemAsync(user_id, password, options).then(function() {
        dispatch(authUser(user_id));
        console.log('I am in')
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Its an error')
        dispatch(addAlert("Could not log in."));
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(addAlert("Could not log in."));
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way you are constructing your promise chain.

```js
const promiseOne = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('p1')
})

const promiseTwo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('p2')
})


promiseOne.then(
    (res) => {
      console.log('res', res)
      return promiseTwo
    })
  .then((res2) => {
    console.log('res2', res2)
  })
```

basically you need to return the call to Expo